# react native - aws signature - get request failing with : "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided."

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, get, api-gateway, aws-signature

After it took me two weeks to get a POST request running with the 'agnostic-aws-signature' package I wanted to also make a GET request. Since them I am again two weeks on debugging this one getting the 403 message all day long.

I have tried probably all packages that are out there already with POST - with the result that just agnostic worked for me.

After trying a few days with that one on the GET request, I began to put together my own code for the signature creation, also because the error message is giving me the canonical request and string to sign which I could not review with the packages. Now those two match 100% from the error message to my code, still I am getting the same error message.

Now here is the full message:

> "error": "The request signature we calculated does not match the
> signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing
> method. Consult the service documentation for details.The Canonical
> String for this request should have been

```
GET
/dev-myapp-status/myappstatus
creation_time=1644990779295&myapp_id=f0dfb080-cea3-4111-828f-39c945e010a3
host:api.meetus.app
x-amz-content-sha256:
x-amz-date:20220315T100602Z
host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```

> The String-to-Sign should have been

```
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20220315T100602Z
20220315/eu-central-1/execute-api/aws4_request
bc72522ed88d2e8e59a40f756e43cf97f08f01eebe3bbeee57e9ef876396ceb4
```

**With my own implementation this looks 100% the same as what I have**, because I can control it now. (Please spare me to post the same lines again..)

Also I checked the Credentials *probably more than is good for my mental health*.. I can fetch new IAM creds and those are the ones that I use. (Which is why I later add the sec-token to the headers..)

In my view that means there must be something wrong with the code that comes afterwards.
So I will only post this code here, I hope someone can help.

create ksign:

```
async function createSignatureKey(
  secretkey,
  authDate,
  regionName,
  serviceName,
) {
  let kDate = await hmac('AWS4' + secretkey, authDate, 'binary');

  let kRegion = await hmac(kDate, regionName, 'binary');

  let kService = await hmac(kRegion, serviceName, 'binary');

  let kSigning = await hmac(kService, 'aws4_request', 'binary');

  return kSigning;
}
```

create signature:

```
var hmacSignature = await hmac(kSigning, stringToSign, 'binary');
var signature = await toHex(hmacSignature);
```

and to hex:

```
async function toHex(str) {
  var result = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    result += str.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
  }
  return result;
}
```

After this I only put together the headers, if I do something wrong there aws gives me a good and very specific answer what is wrong. So I think the issue really is the signature calculation outlined here.

Comment: Why are you calculating the signature yourself?? If you want to do that you should spend a couple of weeks looking at the existing implementations, reading the documentation, running the most basic requests you can think of, etc.

Comment: As I described I already tried with all the packages that are out there for react native. With only one positive result for POST - I spent already too much time on this. Additionally the error message that I am getting from aws I could not verify without putting together my own code.